# vuex unknown action type when registering module from plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a plugin with its own store. The store seems to register OK when the plugin is installed and I can see the state under the given namespace in vue dev tools, but the component in the plugin has no access to the state and when I try to call an action it is not found.

I'm pretty sure it is a namespacing issue, but I can't figure out what to add where in the install function.

In the plugin, the store looks like this:

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({

  namespaced: true,
  state: { counter: 0 },
  getters: {},

  mutations: { increment: (state) => { state.counter += 1 } },

  actions: { plusone: ({ commit }) => {
                      alert('Inside plusone Action: ')
                      commit('increment');
                },  
  }
})
```

And my plugin install file looks like this:

```
import component from './SimpleCounter.vue'
import store from './store'

function install(Vue, options) {
  if (install.installed) return
  install.installed = true

  if (!options || !options.store) { throw new Error('Please initialise plugin with a Vuex store.') }

  options.store.registerModule('simpleCounter', store)

  Vue.component('SimpleCounter', component)
}

  const plugin = { install }
...
```

The method in the component is a simple dispatch:

```
   increment () { 
       this.$store.dispatch('plusone') 
   }
```

In the parent app that is consuming the plugin, this is how it is added:

```
import SimpleCounter from 'mcflyal'
Vue.use(SimpleCounter, { store })

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({ router, store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The vuex docs there is mention of "receive a namespace value via your plugin option", but I don't know if that is the right way and how.

Comment: Have you tried to dispatch with the module name? `this.$store.dispatch('simpleCounter/plusone') `. Also accessing state via the module? `this.$store.state.simpleCounter.counter`

Comment: It looks like you're creating two stores. I don't think that's what you want. The thing you pass to `registerModule` should be a module, not a store. Remove the calls to `Vue.use(Vuex)` and `new Vuex.Store` and just export the module configuration object instead. The only actual store (created using `new Vuex.Store`) should be the one you pass to `new Vue`. As your module is namespaced you'll then need to use the `simpleCounter/` prefix when dispatching actions.

Comment: @JesusGalvan I could access the state with your suggestion, thanks and as per skirtle's suggestion, I exported the module object without creating a store and it worked. The dispatch works with the prefix. this.$store.dispatch('simpleCounter/plusone'). I was having this problem because I was creatign the store to test if the component worked in the plugin. For testing I'll change it into a module to have the same structure as with the plugin parent.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle, your comment solved my issue :)